# Best way to implement a queue in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to use a queue in javascript.  So I guess I can do 1 of 3 things:

1. javascript push, shift
2. array.push(), array[0], array.splice(0,1) etc.
3. Queue.js at http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/queues/#download

So I was reading the queue.js and was confused about the benchmarks because I don't really know what the numbers mean.  Also, I'm guessing there are better ways of doing a queue than the 3 I mentioned.

So what's the best way of implementing a queue in javascript and why?  Also if anyone could explain the advantages and disadvantages among the 3 ways I described, that would be very helpful.  Thanks !

Comment: Do you need to do 1000s of calculations in short time?

Comment: You have to say why you care?  If it's about performance, then run a jsperf yourself on whatever in/out patter you think you will have.  If it's something else you care about, you have to say what that is.  If I were doing it, I'd use the push/shift because it's so simple.

Comment: i am concerned about performance and was looking at the benchmarks of queue.js but i'm not sure what the number mean?

Comment: The benchmark in my browser (Firefox 6) shows that native Array methods are always faster than queue.js, so it looks like shift() and unshift() have been optimized. Unless you need to support older browsers, you shouldn't bother using a library.

Comment: I've done my own testing against iojs array methods v1.5, and with the particular access pattern I'm using (enqueue 1000, dequeue 500, enqueue 500, dequeue 1000) Queue.js (and my own solution) handily beat the array solution.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a basic Queue definition, which works just perfectly for me.

```
queue: function() {
    var items;

    this.enqueue = function(item) {
        if (typeof(items) === 'undefined') {
            items = [];   
        }

        items.push(item);                       
    }

    this.dequeue = function() {
        return items.shift();                                                
    }

    this.peek = function(){
        return items[0];                  
    }
}
```

Comment: What's that advantage, for you, of making queue an object with methods instead of an array (and using `push()`, `shift()`, and `[0]` directly)?

Comment: Well, that's a common coding practice to have meaningful APIs (of course, over basic data types), especially to improve code readability and interpretation. Also, giving you the opportunity to alter your implementation, if required, at a later point in time, while not changing the callers'.

Answer (score 1):

Queue.js is using something like your second proposition but it's less efficient because it requires unneeded tests, native methods are better optimized. I would definitively use Sacket's solution.